# AuthService.Authenticate does not create a persistent session when RememberMe = true. Intentional?

Tags: servicestack

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that is following the example in the ServiceStack.UseCases/CustomAuthenticationMvc project, where the account controller logs authenticates with ServiceStack when the user logs in to the MVC site by setting the AuthService's RequestContext and then calling Authenticate(). This works, but I noticed that even when RememberMe is true, no ss-opt cookie with "perm" is sent to the client. I poked around a little bit and found the code in AuthService.Post that sets this session option and added it to my code, and now I do get the ss-opt cookie and I can close the browser and re-open it to my project's URL and authentication succeeds using the persistent cookie. So, I have my solution or workaround, but it seemed odd that this behavior would be omitted from the Authenticate method, so I wanted to ask here: is this intentional or is it a bug?

Comment: I can confirm this too.  I've submitted a pull request to add RememberMe behaviour to the AuthServices Authenticate method.